# Move an Object Up and Down(Jump) in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I making an app in which, there is an apple on a plate. And I want to place this apple on plate and then after placing to make this apple jump until the user can not click on it. I do not know how to do this.

Any help regarding moving apple up and down on plate. Any class through which I can accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [2D graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) or [OpenGl](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) for attaining such effects, 2D graphics will be easy to implement  but if you want improved performance use openGL. This can be combined with you apps logic.

Answer (score 0):

example:
XML file saved at res/anim/rocket.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

This application code will set the animation as the background for a View, then play the animation:

```
ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocket_image);
rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);

rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
rocketAnimation.start();
```

Here you can use set of drawables and start animation, once view clicked then you can stop animation by calling **rocketAnimation.stop();**

Comment: actually i want to work without frames . Only for the apple . I want to only make it jump up and down .It's not changing any texture